MERN stack post request problem in Vercel
So today I deployed my first mern stack app in Vercel but I got a problem in this post request which was working perfectly in localhost :
    const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('price', productData.price);
    formData.append('name', productData.name);
    formData.append('description', productData.description);


    productData.selectedColors.forEach((color) => {
      formData.append('colors', color);
    });
    const materialArray = productData.materials
      .split(/[,\n;]/)
      .map((material) => material.trim())
      .filter((material) => material !== '');
    materialArray.forEach((material) => {
      formData.append('materials', material);
    });


    productData.selectedSizes.forEach((sizes) => {
      formData.append('sizes', sizes);
    });
    productData.categories.forEach((categories) => {
      formData.append('categories', categories);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < productData.photos.length; i++) {
      formData.append('photos', productData.photos[i]);
    }
    // Include the seller's ID from the token
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const decodedToken = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
    formData.append('sellerId', decodedToken.userId);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://maker-app-backend.vercel.app/products', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
      });

      console.log('Product added successfully:', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding product:', error);
    }
  };

please consider that all the data is correct and this code was working also here is the backend code :
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "uploads", "photos"));
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix + extension);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.post(
  "/products",
  authenticateUser,
  upload.array("photos"),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.user.role);
      if (req.user.role !== "seller") {
        return res
          .status(403)
          .json({ error: "Only sellers are allowed to add products" });
      }

      const productData = req.body;
      const photos = req.files.map((file) => path.basename(file.path)); // Get paths of all uploaded files
      const product = new productModel({
        sellerId: productData.sellerId,
        price: productData.price,
        name: productData.name,
        description: productData.description,
        colors: productData.colors,
        materials: productData.materials,
        sizes: productData.sizes,photos: photos,
        categories: productData.categories,
      });
      const savedProduct = await product.save();

      // Log paths of all uploaded files
      photos.forEach((path) => {
        console.log("File uploaded:", path);
      });

      res.status(201).json(savedProduct);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error adding product:", error);
      res.status(500).send("Error adding product to the database");
    }
  }
);

also everything here worked fine but now I get an internal server error
I changed the way of sending data also I removed photos adding completely but the problem is still there. Also note that every other post request is working perfectly.
